Backwards Euler on System of Equations
I have a second order differential equation
y'' + 5y' + 3y = sin(pi*t/4)

I have decomposed it into the following single order differential equations
x1 = y
x2 = y'

x1' = x2
x2' = -5x2 - 3x1 + sin(pi*t/4)

Then I find the difference equations for the backwards euler method
x1(n+1) = x1(n) + h*x2(n+1)

x2(n+1) = x2(n) + h*(-5x2(n+1)-3x1(n+1) + sin(pi*t(n+1)/4)
(1-5h)x2(n+1) = x2(n) + h*(-3x1(n+1) + sin(pi*t(n+1)/4)
x2(n+1) = (x2(n) + h*(-3x1(n+1) + sin(pi*t(n+1)/4)) / (1-5h)

Given that y(0) = 0 and y'(0) = 0 I need to numerically compute y from 0 to 10 with steps of 0.05.
I'm not sure how I should go about doing this however as instead of one equation I have two.
So far I have tried

h = 0.05;
y = []

x1 = 0
x2 = 0

for t = 0 to 10 by h

    x2 = (x2 + h(-3x1 + sin(pi*t/4))) / (1-5h)
    x1 = x1 + h(x2)
    append x1 to y

end for

This gives me solution that is wildly off from the correct solution. What am I doing wrong?

linear system -> Gauss algorithm /// You have a sign error in our partial transformation.

A sign error? Can you point out where please? Also how would I go about solving a system of equations like this with a Gauss algorithm?

The problem appears here:
x2(n+1) = x2(n) + h*(-5x2(n+1)-3x1(n+1) + sin(pi*t(n+1)/4)
(1-5h)x2(n+1) = x2(n) + h*(-3x1(n+1) + sin(pi*t(n+1)/4)

When you move x2(n+1) term from RHS to LHS, you never change the sign of 5. Hence, your numerical solution explodes. When fixed, it goes back to normal.
Here is a sample of Python code to prove it works well:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def system(y, t):
     x1, x2 = y
     dydt = [x2, -5*x2 - 3*x1 + np.sin(np.pi*t/4)]
     return dydt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))

h = 0.1;
y = []

x1 = x2 = 0
ts = np.linspace(0, 10, int(10 / h))

for t in ts:
    x2 = (x2 + h*(-3*x1 + np.sin(np.pi*t/4))) / (1+5*h)
    x1 = x1 + h*x2
    y.append(x1)

y0 = [0.0, 0.0]
sol = odeint(system, y0, ts)

plt.plot(ts, y, marker='.', markersize=4, label='Numerical')
plt.plot(ts, sol[:, 0], marker='.', markersize=4, label='ODEInt')

plt.legend(); plt.grid(ls=':', alpha=.4); plt.xlabel('time'); plt.ylabel('y(t)');


